# Proportional sorting of web scrape results

Tags: python, algorithm

If you have a given list of lists what's the best way to sort them proportionally? Is there a better way to do this?

The idea is that in a case of web scraping, you would want to avoid hitting google all the time and want to distribute calls so that they are as even as possible.

Is this a thing that can be done more efficiently than this terribad code that I wrote?

```
urls = [
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://duckduckgo.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://bing.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://yahoo.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://yahoo.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://bing.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://yahoo.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://altavista.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://yahoo.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://altavista.com/search','redirect.com', 0],
        ['http://google.com/search','redirect.com', 0]
    ]

def get_domain( url ):
    domain = ''
    parts = tldextract.extract( url )
    if parts.subdomain != '' and parts.subdomain != 'www':
        domain = parts.subdomain + '.' + parts.domain + '.' + parts.suffix
    else:
        domain = parts.domain + '.' + parts.suffix
    return domain


def proportional_sort( urls ):
    doms = [get_domain(url[0]) for url in urls]
    dom_set = set(doms)


    matrix = {}
    for domain in dom_set:
        sublist = [item for item in urls if get_domain(item[0]) == domain]
        # print sublist
        random.shuffle(sublist)
        if len(sublist) in matrix:
            matrix[len(sublist)][domain] = sublist
        else:
            matrix[len(sublist)] = {}
            matrix[len(sublist)][domain] = sublist

    # print matrix.keys()

    map_vector = []

    for key in matrix:
        map_vector += [key] * key * len(matrix[key])
        map_vector = sorted(map_vector, key=int)

    # print map_vector

    proportionally_sorted = []

    for pos in map_vector:
        if pos in matrix:
            rand_pos = [pos]
            for key in matrix.keys():
                if key % pos == 0:
                    rand_pos.append(key)
            for position in rand_pos:
                rand_keys = matrix[position].keys()
                random.shuffle(rand_keys)
                for key in rand_keys:
                    rand = rand_keys.pop()
                    if matrix[position][rand]:
                        proportionally_sorted.append(matrix[position][rand].pop())
                        break
                    else:
                        continue

    return proportionally_sorted
```

Comment: Could you better explain what uohre tryingto do? Are yoj saying uou want urls pointing to google to be spread out evenly amongst the others?

Comment: The idea I'm trying to accomplish is to distribute the domains as equally as possible. In this case, there are 8 google URLs, 4 yahoo, 2 bing, 2 altavista, and 1 duckduckgo.

The idea is that I don't want to sort them by domain if I'm putting them in a queue to get scraped. I want to evenly distribute them as much as possible.

Comment: Im on mobile so linking is a pain. Googled for "python sort like items furthest apart" showed some promising solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what your code is supposed to do but I can see some room for improvement so let's go!

**Style**

Your code looks good and PEP 8 seems to be respected. I find the spacing in the argument lists a bit unusual but he... Also, your functions probably deserves some documentation like docstrings for instance.

**Improvements**

`domain = ''` is not needed here.

---

In :

```
    random.shuffle(sublist)
    if len(sublist) in matrix:
        matrix[len(sublist)][domain] = sublist
    else:
        matrix[len(sublist)] = {}
        matrix[len(sublist)][domain] = sublist
```

You don't need to call `len` over and over again.

```
    random.shuffle(sublist)
    leng = len(sublist)
    if leng in matrix:
        matrix[leng][domain] = sublist
    else:
        matrix[leng] = {}
        matrix[leng][domain] = sublist
```

Then, you could remove the duplicated logic :

```
    random.shuffle(sublist)
    leng = len(sublist)
    if leng not in matrix:
        matrix[leng] = {}
    matrix[leng][domain] = sublist
```

But the part with the test and the empty dict could be done automatically with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)s.

---

In :

```
def proportional_sort( urls ):
    doms = [get_domain(url[0]) for url in urls]
    dom_set = set(doms)

    matrix = {}
    for domain in dom_set:
        sublist = [item for item in urls if get_domain(item[0]) == domain]
```

it seems like you are using the wrong data structure. You want to iterate over domains only and only once and then process the corresponding urls. It would be better to define a dictionnary mapping domains to list of urls once so that you don't have to call `get_domain` many times in many places. You have different ways to do this, the best involves `setdefault` :

```
dom_dict = {}
for url in urls:
    dom_dict.setdefault(get_domain(url[0])).append(url)
```

Then, your code becomes (not tested):

```
matrix = {}
for domain, sublist in dom_dict.iteritems():
    random.shuffle(sublist)
    leng = len(sublist)
    if leng not in matrix:
        matrix[leng] = {}
    matrix[leng][domain] = sublist
```